# c++11 Global initialization order and thread_local

Tags: c++, c++11, static, initialization, thread-local-storage

Hi when running the following using gcc 4.8.1 when using the thread_local keyword the assertion is hit. When removing the thread_local the assert is not hit. Does anyone know why this is? There is some undefined global ordering but I would expect buf_ to have a valid address before assigning ptr_. Just remove the keyword thread_local and it works for me.

Output:

```
$ ./ThreadLocal 
 Running Tester 
ThreadLocal: main.cpp:13: int main(): Assertion `buf == ptr' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Output when removing thread_local keyword
 Running Tester
```

Test.hpp

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cassert>

template <typename std::size_t N>
struct Mem
{
    Mem() noexcept: ptr_(buf_)
    {}

    char * getBuf() { return buf_; }
    char * getPtr() { return ptr_; }

private:
    char buf_[N];
    char * ptr_;
};



template <typename std::size_t N>
struct Tester
{
    Tester()
    {
        std::cout << " Running Tester " << std::endl;
    }

    char * getPtr() { return _mem.getPtr(); }
    char * getBuf() { return _mem.getBuf(); }

private:
    static thread_local Mem<N> _mem;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Test.hpp"

template <typename std::size_t N>
thread_local Mem<N> Tester<N>::_mem;

int main()
{
    Tester<500> t;
    char * ptr  = t.getPtr();
    char * buf = t.getBuf();

    assert( buf == ptr );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug in GCC. Apparently `Tester::_mem` is not being initialized at all. [GCC 4.9.0 does the same](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9bd4ffee048a049), but [clang 3.5.0 works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a867223f64412f5d)

Making `_mem` not dependent on template parameter [makes GCC crash](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b487407b297b3d6c).

Finally, making `Tester` a non-template class [makes GCC work at last](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26b213153a2e871a).

Update:  These seem to be [known](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60702) [bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58624) in GCC.